# Exception read data from file while split character "|"

Tags: java

```
public void loadDataFromFile(ArrayList<Book> list, String fileName) {
    File f = new File(fileName);
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        while (sc.hasNext()) { 
            String perLine = sc.nextLine(); //get date per line
            String txt[] = perLine.split("|");
            list.add(new Book(txt[0], txt[1], Integer.parseInt(txt[2]), Double.parseDouble(txt[3])));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My function read data from file and add data to arraylist. But when I run this function, it have bug like this picture
[image]

My file is `book.txt` and data of this file is
`A2|Hoa|22|50.3`. If i try split at character `"|"`, it will have bug like this picture. But if i change data of file to `A2 Hoa 22 50.3` and split at `" "` it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java `String` `split()` method work's with regex as argument since '|' is special character in regex you need to escape it with \\ as folowing `perLine.split("\\|");`

Comment: thanks, if my data contain '|' and '    ', so how to split it   `A2   |    Hoa   |   22 |   50.3`

Comment: `String txt[] = perLine.split("\\|").stream().map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);` should work